# Does the MarkLogic Library Services API store complete copies of document versions?

Tags: storage, document-versioning

How are document changes stored using the MarkLogic Library Services API?

Answer (score 1):

When you initially put a document under Library Services management, it creates Version 1 of the document. Each time you update the document, a new version of the document is created and stored in the database. You can specify a retention policy to determine how many versions back you want to keep.

See http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/dls#chapter for more details.